# How do I make a delay on a onclick display to none function

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, delay

I have this script, but i there needs to be a 2sec. delay from I click on the 'playblock'-function, till it happens.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function playblock()
{
 document.getElementById("playbox").style.display="none";    
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout):

```
function playblock() {    
  window.setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("playbox").style.display="none"; }, 2000);
}
```